# Convergence of random saddle point

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $y_n^*$ be the solution of
$$
y = g_n(y)
$$
where $g_n(\cdot)$ is a random function. Suppose that for fixed $y$
$$
g_n(y)\to h(y)
$$
almost surely and pointwise as $n\to\infty$. Is there any conditions under which $(y_n^*)_n$, as a sequence of random variables, converge to the solution of $y = h(y)$ ?

Comment: I believe it should be uniform convergence with respect to $y$. Otherwise $g_n(y_n^*)$ might not converge. For the sake of simplicity remove randomality and you will see.

Comment: What about conditions with regard to $g_n(\cdot)$ and $h(\cdot)$?

Comment: Well IMHO it does not matter it just adds additional dimension (prob measure, sigma algebra). As I see you will get almost sure convergence of $y^*_n$ then. I will derive the formalism  may be later.

Comment: Is $h(\cdot)$ a random fucntion? BTW you mean "random function" the function that randomly selected from theset of functions or the function of a random variable?

Comment: Thanks. $h(\cdot)$ is not a random function, and by "random function" I mean a function of a random variable..

Comment: Than it becomes completely unclear for me. If $g_n$ is just a function of random variable $y$ then a.s. convergence for each $y$ is senseless.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that $g_n$ is "randomly selected from set of functions"..